# XAML Rectangle event Tapped doesn't fire in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have a simple Rectangle in XAML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" IsTapEnabled="True" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FF72BB5C" Stroke="#FFFB0000" Tapped="rect_Tapped"/>
```

It draws fine but when I try and click on it nothing happens.

I have tried making the stroke bigger and clicking that and nothing.

I have tried lots of the other events associated with the Rectangle and nothing fires.

Would there be a problem calling the Tapped event when I'm using a mouse and not a touch screen?

Comment: I don't see anything awry here... what do you have in rect_Tapped to act on the click?

Comment: testText.Text = "Hello";

I put a breakpoint on this line as well so I'll definitely know if it has fired.

Comment: I can confirm that your xaml fires the tap event with both the mouse and with touch.

Comment: is there more context to this app? this definitely should be working, and if you start a new blank app and try it, you should see that as well.

Comment: I had the Rectangle inside of the Grid given by default when you create a Blank App. When I remove the Grid and have the Rectangle by itself it fires correctly!

Comment: there's more to it than that, since I have the same setup... you have any other elements in the grid?

Comment: <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" IsTapEnabled="True" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FF72BB5C" Stroke="#FFFB0000" Tapped="rect_Tapped"/>
            
        </Canvas>
        <TextBlock Name="Test"  Text="Hi" />
    </Grid>

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue. Solved with `IsHitTestVisible` property for `Rectangle` and every view above it. `True` for rect and `False` for others. Though `True` is default, could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I just found strange and funny solution for this.

If your layout looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" IsTapEnabled="True" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FF72BB5C" Stroke="#FFFB0000" Tapped="rect_Tapped"/>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Name="Test" Text="Hi" />
</Grid>
```

Then change it to this:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" IsTapEnabled="True" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FF72BB5C" Stroke="#FFFB0000" Tapped="rect_Tapped"/>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Test" Text="Hi" />
</Grid>
```

I just added `VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to `TextBlock` and now it works. Don't know why, but works. I'm going to go deeper into this issue.